# Viewpager with scrollview, best way to keep the scrollposition in sync across pages?

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, scrollview

I am using a viewpager to switch through fragments. Each fragment has a scrollview which I would like keep in sync for all pages. What is the best approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is Inter Fragment communications, probably best is to have a shared view model between the fragments (there are other ways and the shared viewmodel approach is documented at https://androidwave.com/passing-data-between-fragments/ )

You would then store the amount the current scrollview using https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getScrollY%28%29 in the shared viewmodel and then use that value to set the new view scroll amount https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setScrollY(int)

IF you are using a modern version of Viewpager (https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager/widget/ViewPager or Viewpager2) this maintains the correct liefcycle of the Fragments with only the current displayed Fragment being in the `Resumed` state and the others being in `Paused` state if they exist.
See https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter#BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT for more details

As the other Fragments are not guaranteed to exist and it would be computationally expensive and complicated to try and scroll the other Fragments in real time then you would just use the lifecycle to manage this.

So in each Fragment in the `onPause` method you would `getScrollY` and store the value in your shared viewmodel.
Then in each Fragment in the `onResume` method you would `setScrollY` from the value in the shared viewmodel.

Thus the viewpager would store the current scroll position as you started the page switch and set the scroll position on the incoming page.